# iPhone SDK: Audio Queue not loud enough for me

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audioqueue

I would like all the tricks into making the playback as loud as possible on my iPhone app. I'm recording using Audio Queue and am not sure if there is a way to make the input louder. On playback I'm setting the kAudioQueueParam_Volume parameter to 1.0.

It's still not loud enough. There our apps that do kind of what I'm doing that are much louder.

Is Audio Queue quieter than other Core Audio API's? 
Is there any tricks that are known that someone could share?

FYI, I'm using the AQRecorder and AQPlayer from the SpeakHere Sample App.

Comment: What Audio Session category is your app using during playback?

Comment: I'm using the play and record category.

Answer (score 2):

When playing back your recording, try set the AudioSession to Playback category.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm now setting the category to MediaPlayback in AQPlayer::SetupNewQueue and to PlayAndRecord in AQRecorder::StartRecord. An alternative is to play back audio with AVAudioPlayer, which uses full volume regardless of the audio session category.